# GROUP BY and DISTINCT not working

Tags: sql, group-by, distinct

With `Group by`

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3
FROM Table
GROUP BY Column1, Column2, Column3
ORDER BY Column1
```

and with `Distinct`

```
SELECT DISTINCT Column1, Column2, Column3
FROM Table
ORDER BY Column1
```

these queries don't get an error but they don't group my results. I try to group by Column1. What can be wrong with these queries ?
Thank you in advance.

Edit :
With these queries, I get the results as
Value1  Value2
Value1  Value3
Value3  Value4
Value4  Value5
Value4  Value6

But I want to get the result as
Value1  Value2
Value3  Value4
Value4  Value5

Edit :
Sorry, I got my fault; Value5 and Value6 are unique values so they can't be ommited...

Comment: `these queries don't group my records`, what do you mean?, it certainly should be grouping your results. I think that what you want is something different than what you wrote

Comment: Probably a character set quirk. Please provide more information.

Comment: Sample data would help .. show a few rows before the query and after .. and also show what you expect to happen.

Comment: second sql statement only order the result, the first one does it

Comment: @hqtunes   Atleast give details of what results you are expecting

Comment: @hqtunes: in your post you want to show "Value4 Value5" but not "Value4 Value6" ?? Why not .. please explain your logic.

Comment: Thank you for all, I got my fault while I'm giving the detail to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by ommiting columns that are having unique values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Column1 FROM Table ORDER BY Column1
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample test showing results:

```
  SQL> create table junk (
    2     col1  number,
    3     col2  number,
    4     col3  number
    5     )
    6  /

  Table created.

  SQL>
  SQL> insert into junk values ( 100, 200, 300 );

  1 row created.

  SQL> insert into junk values ( 100, 200, 300 );

  1 row created.

  SQL> insert into junk values ( 100, 200, 400 );

  1 row created.

  SQL> insert into junk values ( 400, 200, 300 );

  1 row created.

  SQL>
  SQL> commit;

  Commit complete.

  SQL>
  SQL> select col1, col2, col3
    2    from junk
    3   group by col1, col2, col3
    4   order by col1
    5  /

        COL1       COL2       COL3
  ---------- ---------- ----------
         100        200        300
         100        200        400
         400        200        300

  SQL> select distinct col1, col2, col3 from junk order by col1;

        COL1       COL2       COL3
  ---------- ---------- ----------
         100        200        300
         100        200        400
         400        200        300

  SQL>
```

Show something similar with different data if this doesn't work ... fully reproducible and re-runnable. (I used Oracle, however, above should work in any database)

Notice how both queries "combined" the first 2 rows (100, 200, 300) into a "single" row.  That's what's happening. If you want something else to happen, add more details to explain ;)

Comment: Thank you Ditto, I got my fault. I tried to group by Column1 but all Column2 values and all Column3 values was not unique. Thats why I couldn't group by Column1 as I expected.